# How to reduce waiting time for open connection?

Tags: c#, database-connection

I check connection is available with code:

```
 SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(string.Concat(connectionString));
        try
        {
            objConnection.Open(); // this line make wait time if connection not available 
            objConnection.Close();
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
```

When connection not available, It takes a long time to answer .how can reduce it?

Comment: If you're connecting over the TCP protocol you could try if the server is configured to respond to a simple ping and use that instead before you initiate a real TCP connection. I assume your client has a network connection going.

Comment: I dont have access to configuration server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're connecting to your SQL Server you can try to [`Ping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) the server first. On my box a ping only takes 5 seconds to conclude that a server is not reachable. The simplest code that leverages that feature is shown in this snippet:

```
if(new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping().Send("Your servername here").Status != 
       System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.TimedOut)
 {
    // server reachable, try a real SQL Server connection now
    SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
   try
   {
       objConnection.Open(); // this line make wait time if connection not available 
       objConnection.Close();
       // not sure why you would want this
       // only use if you want worse performance
       // SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
      return true; 
   }
   catch
   {
       return false; 
   }
}
else 
{
    return false; // PING failed
}
```

System administrators might disable/block ICMP traffic so this option might not work for every server.

Answer (score 1):

You can check sql connection this way, this won't take long

```
        SqlConnection objConnection = new SqlConnection(string.Concat(connectionString));
        try
        {
           objConnection.Open();
        }
        catch {}

        if (objConnection != null && objConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
               objConnection.Close();
            }
            catch {}
            return true;
        }
        else if (objConnection != null && objConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            try
            {
               objConnection.Close();
            }
            catch {}
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: without open you have no choice to check, and if you try open it and fail then it will definitely take time, because it will try for reconnect then report you that it can't open

Comment: how can reduce this time( it will try for reconnect)? Is it possible?

Comment: see my latest update and go through this helpful explanation question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853371/most-efficient-way-to-test-sql-connection-string-availibility

Comment: @MostafizurRahman, you better close this connection before returning.

Answer (score 1):

Do not `ClearAllPools`! The connection pool is there specifically to make connecting more efficient. When you `Open()` a connection from the pool is used (if there is one). When you  `Close()` it is returned to the pool but not destroyed, just waiting for someone to use it again.